# Program to determine if a point is in a given circle.

Tags: geometry

I need to develop a program that takes the radius of a circle centered at the origin($r$) and coordinates of a point $(x,y)$ and returns true if $(x,y)$ is inside the circle, I haven't taken a geometry class in a while so I'm kind of lost.if this isn't enough information please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Every answer so far is correct.  I just want to point out in terms of simplicity of code, if the origin is $(0,0)$ then $(y-0)^2$ or $(x - 0)^2$ is simply $x^2$ and $y^2$ and you don't need to bother to find the actual distance by taking the square root; you can simply compare the square of the distance to the square of the radius.

So in the simplest code:

If $x^2 + y^2 < r^2$ then $(x,y)$ is inside the circle.

If $x^2 + y^2 > r^2$ then $(x,y)$ is outside the circle.

If $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ then $(x,y)$ is a point of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Can you compute the distance from the centre and check that this is less than the radius $r$? If the centre is the origin you need

$\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} \le r.$

But generally (origin at $(x_0,y_0)$) it will be

$\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2 +(y-y_0)^2} \le r.$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Do you know the distance formula?

$$\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}=\text{Distance between}\;(x_1,y_1)\; \text{and} \; (x_2,y_2)$$

If a point, say $(x,y)$, lies inside a circle centered at origin what can you say about the distance of $(x,y)$ from the origin.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the distance formula between 2 points. Let $A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2, y_2)$ be any two points in the $xy$ plane and let $D$ be the distance between them. Then $D$ = $\sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2}$.

In your case the two points are origin $O(0,0)$ and the given point $P(x,y)$. Let the distance be $D$. If $D$ < radius, then $P$ lies inside the circle. If $D$ = radius, P lies on the circle. Else P lies outside the circle. By the distance formula we have $D$ = $\sqrt{(0 - x)^2 + (0 - y)^2}$ or simply $D$ = $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$